# Determining the size of the UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to dtermine the width of the cell that I'm in when i am creating my thumbnails (it's for an app very similar to the photos app on the iphone).

This is what I have:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
int photoWidth = self.frame.size.width / 4;
    thumbnail1 = [[ThumbnailButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, photoWidth, 40) ];
    thumbnail2 = [[ThumbnailButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(photoWidth, 0, photoWidth, 40) ];
    thumbnail3 = [[ThumbnailButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(photoWidth * 2, 0, photoWidth, 40) ];
    thumbnail4 = [[ThumbnailButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(photoWidth * 3, 0, photoWidth, 40) ];
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self.contentView addSubview:thumbnail1];
        [self.contentView addSubview:thumbnail2];
        [self.contentView addSubview:thumbnail3];
        [self.contentView addSubview:thumbnail4];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My main problem is with:

```
int photoWidth = self.frame.size.width / 4;
```

I cannot figure out the height and width of the Table Cell.

Any help would be appreciated,
Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: not your question really, but there's some memory leaking here. Add `[... autorelease]` to all those `alloc` statements.

Comment: Thank you for catching that!  I'm still fairly new to Objective-C

Comment: Also at this point you're trying to create a grid no doubt, in which case, don't do it this way. Utilize existing mature code. `AQGridView` would be a good fit here, all you'd have to do is shove your image into a cell, and if the number of cells * your cell width doesn't divide evenly against your superview width, just adjust the content offset so everything lines up right. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point the table cell which is in the making cannot know how big it will be, unless you tell it. It also has no reference to the tableview it will be added to, so there is no way.

You could just use some size, set the appropriate resizing masks and when adding the cell, determine the frame with dimensions from `tableView.frame.size`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on " set the appropriate resizing masks and when adding the cell, determine the frame with dimensions from tableView.frame.size"

Comment: Just pick some size (preferably: the correct size) and make the table cell perfect for that size. Then later on, when the cell is set up and ready to be returned from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, set the true size. You can get the true size from the tableview, of course. Because you will probably add the table-view-cell to a table-view. Right?

Comment: regarding the resizing mask, have a read at apple.com: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html *"When creating a view, it is important to assign an appropriate value to the autoresizingMask property to ensure the view resizes correctly."*